# Sample DVD Rental database, find a customers favorite actor

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I've been trying to improve my SQL join skills.  I'm using the classic sample DVD Rental Database (can be found [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/))
).  I am trying to determine a customers favorite actor, by counting up all appearances the actor has appeared in all the movies the customer has rented.

Right now I have this monster query that has 3 sub queries.

```
SELECT email, actor.last_name, count(actor.last_name)
FROM (SELECT email, actor_id
      FROM (SELECT email, film_id
         FROM (SELECT email, inventory_id
              FROM customer as cu
              JOIN rental ON cu.customer_id = rental.customer_id
              ORDER BY email) as sq
         JOIN inventory ON sq.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) as sq2
      JOIN film_actor ON sq2.film_id = film_actor.film_id) as sq3
JOIN actor ON sq3.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY email, actor.last_name
ORDER BY COUNT(actor.last_name) DESC;
```

And what I end up getting is the full list of emails, the actor's last name, and the total number of appearances, like so -
email

```
email                               actor.last_name     count
"debra.nelson@sakilacustomer.org"   "Nolte"             "12"
"nathan.runyon@sakilacustomer.org"  "Guiness"           "11"
"margie.wade@sakilacustomer.org"    "Temple"            "11"
"marsha.douglas@sakilacustomer.org" "Kilmer"            "11"
"veronica.stone@sakilacustomer.org" "Nolte"             "11"
"wendy.harrison@sakilacustomer.org" "Willis"            "10"  etc
```

How can I modify my query so that I only get the top actor for each email, and is there a way to make this query simpler and yield the same results?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of simplifying this query, keep in mind to use table alias's.

Your query is full of unnecessary subquery's that can be boiled down to this:

```
        SELECT cu.email, act.last_name, count(act.last_name)

          FROM customer as cu
          JOIN rental as ren ON cu.customer_id = ren.customer_id
          JOIN inventory as inv ON ren.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id
          JOIN film_actor as fil ON inv.film_id = fil.film_id
          JOIN actor as act ON act.actor_id = fil.actor_id
          group by cu.email,act.last_name
```

Next in terms of attaining the top actor per email address we can apply the row_number() window function and then subquery where row number = 1 to narrow in the results:

```
        Select x.email,x.last_name,x.count from (
        SELECT cu.email, act.last_name, count(act.last_name)
        ,row_number() over(partition by email order by COUNT(act.last_name) DESC )
          FROM customer as cu
          JOIN rental as ren ON cu.customer_id = ren.customer_id
          JOIN inventory as inv ON ren.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id
          JOIN film_actor as fil ON inv.film_id = fil.film_id
          JOIN actor as act ON act.actor_id = fil.actor_id
          group by cu.email,act.last_name
          ) as x 
         where row_number = 1
         ORDER BY x.count DESC;
```

Comment: Ah I just learned about the joining on joins.  Makes a lot of sense.  I did not know about that row_number() or over() or partition function.  I'll look those up.  Thanks for the answer!